How to see logs of crashed pods in a kubernetes cluster
A pod in the Kubernetes cluster has crashed and restarted so many times (150+) to match the replica count in the cluster. Due to this much of restarts, I am unable to troubleshoot, see the logs of the very first crashing point, to see what was the reason initially. I tried using this command kubectl logs <podname> --previous but as the name of the pod is dynamic, I cannot see the logs at all with --previous flag. How can I check the logs in the crashed pods about 2 days ago? Thanks in advance!
